# How to make 2 containers with sql server and dotnet app communicate with each other?

Tags: linux, docker, azure-devops

I have the following project layout inside an Azure DevOps pipeline.

On a hosted Ubuntu agent:

(a) Container “A” is running a mssql server inside a docker container (mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server), the container is exposing port 1433 to the daemon

(b) Container “B” contains all the repo files, where a dotnet core application has been being built.
This container contains also the database migration files (.cs files).

Container B is started with the run command and the entrypoint runs 2 scripts in this order:

1)  Handles the creation and migration of the database
2)  Runs the project: a back-end api that communicates with the database

The dotnet project communicates via this ConnectionString with the database:

```
"Database": "Server=localhost,1433; Database=MyAwesomeDatabase; User=sa; Password=MyAwesomePassword; MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"
```

In this second step, container B exposes the port 55111 for running tests against the API.

The pipeline contains other actions as well, but these are the relevant ones for my issue.
How can I make these 2 containers communicate  correctly, so that the database migration is done on container A, and the API in container B gets connected with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your containers a meaningful name (or use services, which auto-names them), put them on the same Docker network (overlay or bridge, depending on your situation), and use the name of the container as a hostname.

So if your db container is called "mydb", then your connection string would become:

`"Database": "Server=mydb,1433; Database=MyAwesomeDatabase; User=sa; Password=MyAwesomePassword; MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"`

Comment: The container names are asigned inside the Azure DevOps pipeline, but the clue to have this resolved was to name the database server according to the name of the mssql container ```Server=mydb```! That was the biggest help. I created a docker bridge network for the container communications, and now everything looks good!

Comment: Good to hear, El Fred!